# Spring Boot JPA get Table MetaData

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc

I have a Spring Boot application and have my datasource credentials stored in the `application.properties`.

Now I want to have the metadata like `Columnname`, `Datatype`, `Primarykey`,... for a specific table.

My question is, can I achieve it using `JPARepository`. If yes how?

If not which other ways are there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you meant jpa metamodels?

Comment: @emotionlessbananas Oh yeah thank you that's it 
thank you for the keyword :)

Comment: if you think you have found the problem and solution, then please modify it accordingly so that it can be closed :)